# I'm completely new to java and was wondering if there was any way to improve this program

Tags: java

The goal of the program is to take a string and create a pyramid shape using the letters similar to what you can often see on you tube. The program firsts asks the user the string they want to convert, then it asks them whether they want to ignore whitespace, if they decide to ignore whitespace, whitespace will be ignored as the program subtracts/adds characters. Ive been coding for about a week and haven't yet learned how to correctly create classes. Any suggestions on how I could use more advanced coding to improve my code would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String fls = "FALSE";
        String tr = "TRUE";
        Scanner stringWord = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the string you wish to convert: ");
        String example = stringWord.nextLine();
        Scanner whiteSpaceOrNo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nTrue or false, you want to ignore whitespace: ");
        String whiteSpace = whiteSpaceOrNo.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\n");
        if(whiteSpace.toUpperCase().equals(fls))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < example.length()+1; i++)
            {
                if(i < example.length())
                {
                   System.out.println(example.substring(0, i + 1));
                }
                else
                {
                   for(int f = example.length(); f > 0; f--)
                   {
                       System.out.println(example.substring(0, f-1));
                   }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (whiteSpace.toUpperCase().equals(tr))
        {
            for(int d = 0; d < example.length(); d++)
            {
                if(example.charAt(d) != ' ')
                {
                    System.out.println(example.substring(0, d+1));
                }
                if(d == example.length() - 1)
                {
                    for(int x = example.length() - 1; x >= 0; x--)
                    {
                        if(example.charAt(x) != ' ')
                        {
                            System.out.println(example.substring(0, x+1));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect response, restart program");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this code works (really) then it could be a candidate for codereview.stackexchange.com.  The question is "Too Broad" for StackOverflow.

Comment: P.S.  Converting a program this simple to use classes is probably unnecessary.

Comment: Well to start, your program does not ignore the whitespace when asked to. To make things easier, you could use `if (removeWhiteSpace) example.replaceAll("\\s", "");` where `removeWhiteSpace` is a `boolean` as it should be, not a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested improvements:

1. UI

   1. Put user queries and output in a loop so user doesn't have to restart app each time
   2. Don't ask user to type true or false when a simple Y or N (or yes or no) will do. So your query will be: "Ignore whitespace (Y/N)?"
   3. For extra points, work on a GUI.
2. Code Smell / Issues

   1. There is no need for your nested loop. This can be brought out and run after your i-loops that end at `i < example.length()` (in first part, not ignoring whitespace).
   2. By "ignore whitespace" do you mean from the whole pyramid you are building, or just don't have the line where it would have a whitespace character at the end? If the latter, you need to fix your user query; if the former, you need to fix your code
3. Separation of Concerns

   1. Remove the part that actually builds/writes the pyramid strings into a separate method call, or two. The gathering of input from the user is a separate concern to the converting of their string to another output string.
   2. Finally make yourself another class and put that/those method calls into it.